# How do I test my Dock Application

Tags: android, testing, dock

I don't have a Dock, but I'm writing an Dock replacement app.
Can I simulate the Clock Dock somehow?
I know I can for the Car Dock, but that's not the dock I'm replacing.

Can I flip my device to Desk Mode through ADB somehow?
Maybe with something like? `ADB shell sendevent XXX`

Thanks

Comment: adb shell am broadcast -a 'android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT' -ei 'android.intent.extra.DOCK_STATE' 1      doesn't seem to work for some reason...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The adb command above is almost correct. you need to use --ei and not -ei.
the full command I use to simulate docked to car is:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT --ei android.intent.extra.DOCK_STATE 2
```

execute this command from the adb console and that should do it (no permission issues since adb runs in root context)

Only thing missing it that this is supposed to be a sticky broadcast and I don't think there is any way setting it as sticky using adb.

Answer (score 0):

It works by [magnet](http://www.engadget.com/2009/10/28/how-to-hack-your-own-droid-dock-with-magnets-and-cardboard/) so if you have place a strong enough magnet near the back of the device it will think its on a dock. I don't think that will hurt anything in the device either.

Comment: I tried getting magnets to work but I couldn't get it to do anything. Do I need 2 of them? Couldn't find any Nexus One specific info on the web. :(