# How to put android to a car mode without a dock?

Tags: android

I'm developing some kind of Car mode application and I want to replace default home screen while driving. But I want to activate it when user uses NFC label or exceeding the speed limit. I found one app on Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.safedrivingassociation.everyonetexts) that does this, so it is possible, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Good luck! Head on back when you have a question.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109407/how-do-i-test-my-dock-application

Comment: Not helpful if making an app is the goal but I wanted to do this so I just use Lama. It is an actions manager which lets you do things based on events Not sure if it supports nfc though but I know alternatives to it do for sure.

Comment: Did you ever get this working correctly in the end? Particularly the home activity part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. First of all we need to get a UiModeManager instance:

```
UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
```

Next, to put phone to a car mode we just call

```
uiModeManager.enableCarMode(UiModeManager.ENABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_CAR_HOME);
```

To restore default phone mode:

```
uiModeManager.disableCarMode(UiModeManager.DISABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_HOME);
```

That's all. And for our activity that we want it to be a home screen for car mode, we just add intent-filter to a manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_MODE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The docs for enableCarMode() say that the flags parameter has to be 0 but the constant you're providing (ENABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_CAR_HOME) is 1.  Maybe it was deprecated?

Comment: Weird, but according to docs both constants have value of 1 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#ENABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_CAR_HOME But here is from another part of the docs:  ENABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_CAR_HOME
Added in API level 8

Flag for use with enableCarMode(int): go to the car home activity as part of the enable.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly seems like a discrepancy. The docs for the constant say that it "ensures a clean transition between the current activity (in non-car-mode) and the car home activity". When I use the flag, it seems to force a transition, closing the activity and reopening it, even though I ultimately end up on the same screen. If I use 0, my activity's day/night theme changes without my activity noticeably re-opening.